# Nuxt.js script does not get added to head

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, google-identity

I attempted to add the Google Identity services script to `nuxt.config.ts`, which should expose `window.google`.

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    /* snip /*
    head: {
        script: [
            { src: "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" },
        ],
    },
});
```

However, when I try to use it inside of a component, `google` is undefined.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
/* snip */

onMounted(() => {
    // google is not defined
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        callback: signInNew,
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("signIn")!, {
        type: "standard",
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
});
</script>
```

Upon further inspection, I found that the script is not added to the head at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you put it in side the nuxt.config file?
app : { head : script : [ { src ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following way.

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
      head: {
          script: [
              { src: "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" },
          ],
      },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank @henrykohl adding the `head` to `app` instead of directly to the root of the config worked for Nuxt3